# submit data from excel userform to password protected access database

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, adodb

i am trying to submit userform data from excel (2013) to an access database.

without password, this code works fine.

```
Private Sub Addoer_Click()
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim dbPath

dbPath = Sheet16.Range("K18").Value

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & dbPath
```

Now i am trying to use same method to send data from excel to a password protected database (each user has different password). In the excel file, the user id is at Sheet16.Range("K17") and password is at Sheet16.Range("K19")

```
userid = Sheet16.Range("K17").Value
pw = Sheet16.Range("K19").Value
```

i changed the cnn.open line to following

```
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
"Data source=" & dbPath, userid, pw, -1
```

and I am getting this error:

Error -2147217843 (Cannot start your application.The workgroup information file is missing or open exclusively by another User.)

i changed the cnn.open line to this

```
cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & dbPath, """ & userid & """, """ & pw & """, -1
```

and I get this error

Error -2147217843 (Not a valid account name or password).

Is there anybody that can help to point where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt doesn't work, because you are passing in the username as `"user"` when the username is actually `user`.

Regarding your first attempt, I found this note at [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/):

> **Note!** Reports say that a database encrypted using Access 2010 - 2013 default encryption scheme does not work with this connection string. In Access; try options and choose 2007 encryption method instead. That should make it work.

Also, could it be that the database is opened exclusively by another connection / program? If you have the database open in Access and you can design tables / queries, IIRC that means you have exclusive access to the database, and no other connections can connect to it. Do you see an `.laccdb` (or `.ldb`) file in the same folder as the Access database?

**References:**

- [Microsoft OLE DB Proivder for Microsoft Jet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681754%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [ConnectionString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675810(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Formatting Rules for Connection Strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/formating-rules-for-connection-strings/) at connectionstrings.com

Comment: The adodb connection syntax asks for the user id and password to be written in string. If I had defined it as certain cell's value like above, I don't have to put ' " ' around it?

Comment: Yes, I can design tables and queries in the access database. Does it mean that in order to make the code works, I have to set database to open non-exclusively?

Comment: @KZMN Not sure, but I would guess that as you say you only need the double-quotes around the username and password when they're part of the regular connection string; if you're passing them as parameters into `conn.Open` then you probably don't need them.

Comment: @KZMN _in order to make the code work_ -- Test it. If the database is not currently open in Access, does the code work? If it does, then that is the issue.

Comment: I have checked the setting of the database (File>Option>Client Settings>Advanced>Default Open Mode: Shared.) but i still have access to design tables/queries. Also, there is no .laccdb(or .ldb) file in the same folder.